# Pytorch Lightning: How to save a checkpoint for every validation epoch?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

It is not clear from [the docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.10/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.html) how to save a checkpoint for every epoch, and have it actually saved and not instantly deleted, with no followed metric.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
max_epochs = 100
val_every_n_epochs = 1

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        # dirpath=checkpoints_path, # <--- specify this on the trainer itself for version control
        filename="fa_classifier_{epoch:02d}",
        every_n_epochs=val_every_n_epochs,
        save_top_k=-1,  # <--- this is important!
    )
 trainer = Trainer(
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],     
        default_root_dir=checkpoints_path,
        check_val_every_n_epoch=val_every_n_epochs,
        max_epochs=max_epochs,
        gpus=1
    )
```

this will not delete saved checkpoints.

Comment: Here is the reference of the [documentation for ModelCheckpoint](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/api/lightning.pytorch.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html#lightning.pytorch.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint)